# How to write proper decorator to alter classes

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I know I can use closure and inheritance to create a decorator that alter classes.

```
def wrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    class Wrapped(cls):
        """Modify your class here."""

    return Wrapped
```

But if I need to test my new classes to know if they inherit `Wrapped` or not, I can't access `Wrapped` itself to do a straightforward `isinstance` or `issubclass` test.

On the other hand, straightforward inheritance isn't an option. I have about 10 different wrapper which can need to be added to a class. That burden the hierarchy tree way too much.

So I need a way to access the closure from the outside. Or an alternative way to build decorator.

Comment: "But I need to test my new classes to know if they inherit `Wrapped` or not" -- I'm not sure _why_ you need to test that.  Why not test that they behave properly?  Also note that the decorated class will be `Wrapped`, so you could test `DecoratedClass.__name__ == 'Wrapped'` if you really wanted to, but that feels like a hack at best.

Comment: Could your wrappers add some sort of tag method? You could test for the presence of the tag.

Comment: Testing the name isn't an option if I have many `wrapped` object.
Do you mean just `try` to acces the modification and `catch` any error?

Comment: @John That could be an option.

Comment: The excellent answer by @Claudiu is the sort of thing that I had in mind.

Comment: @JohnColeman -- I don't really see how that is much better than checking the class name.  I suppose you're saying that when you end up checking, you'll have a subclass of `Wrapped`?  If that's the case, you could get the class names from the `__mro__`:  `class_names = frozenset(c.__name__ for c in cls.__mro__); print 'Wrapper' in class_names`

Comment: @mgilson -- Nah. The MRO would refer to `closure.Wrapped`. That would be useless since each class returned by `wrapper` would have it's own closure.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to check whether a class has been wrapped by this particular decorator. The most efficacious method to do so may simply be to add a field to that effect, to wit:

```
def wrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    class Wrapped(cls):
        """Modify your class here."""

    Wrapped._is_wrapped_by_this_wrapper = True
    return Wrapped
```

Then you can check `hasattr` and `getattr` of `_is_wrapped_by_this_wrapper`.

If you have multiple wrapper classes that work with each other you may be able to come up with a solution that works better together, e.g. perhaps a `set` consisting of all the names of the wrappers that have been applied.

Comment: Interesting. It would fix my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could inherit from two classes, a base class and `cls`:

```
class WrapperBase:
    pass

def wrapper(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    class Wrapped(cls, WrapperBase):
        """Modify your class here."""

    return Wrapped
```

Now all instances of generated classes test `True` for `isinstance(obj, WrapperBase)`.

Note that `WrapperBase` has no impact on finding inherited methods in the MRO; it comes dead last in any hierarchy (on Python 2, not inheriting from `object` puts it dead last in the MRO, in Python 3 it'll sit between `object` and whatever came before `object` in the MRO of the wrapped class.

Comment: But then I enter the MRO conflicts.. What happens when I need to go up the inheritance tree. The `__init__` is coming to mind.

Comment: @AlexandreParent: `WrapperBase` doesn't define any methods. `super()` won't have a problem with `WrapperBase` when it comes to finding `__init__` and other methods. It comes dead last anyway.